# Excel performance on Pivot-table aggregations

Tags: c#, c++, excel, xml, libreoffice

In my usage of Excel, I'm always surprised at how well Excel does the following two aggregation operations:

1. Date/Time aggregations.
2. Case-insensitive aggregations.

How is Excel able to achieve that performance? Do they store additional data structures for pivot-related information and aggregations? Is this documented anywhere or where could I find out more about that? I've looked at the Libreoffice source code, but the actual product isn't even close to Excel in aggregation/pivot performance.

---

It would be great if someone who understood Excel could share a bit more about the low-level aggregation behavior or structs that Excel uses to achieve this performance -- for example, are they storing any labels twice -- once in its native case and once lower-ed for aggregation purposes? While I know this question is overly broad and not about a code answer per se, and its more conceptual, I'm hoping that an answer may serve as a good reference for methods to optimize performance on excel-style aggregations.

---

Here are a few things that I've noticed based on some suggestions from ARGeo --

(1) There are two files related to Pivot Cache -- Definitions (field-level info):

[image]

(2) And Records (row/cell level info) --

[image]

A few questions from this then:

- How does Excel determine when to store the value as-is vs when to store it as a Shared record. For example, why is value in B2, "LifeLock" (a mixed-case string) stored as-is, but the value in F2, "AZ" is stored as in sharedItems (v="0")?
- Is there any information on the internal C/C++ `Struct` that Excel uses in-memory for its pivotCache (rather than as various XML docs that are stored)?
- Is there any information on how the "helper information" stored at the field-level is used internally by Excel? For example, this information:

.

```
<cacheField name="numEmps" numFmtId="0"><sharedItems containsString="0" containsBlank="1" containsNumber="1" containsInteger="1" minValue="0" maxValue="20000"/></cacheField>
```

---

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. How a monolithic application is able to achieve best-in-class performance doing some operation is something that could potentially require an entire series of blog posts to cover.

Comment: Why the surprise? It's software designed to do stuff just like that.

Comment: For Noticed Things, you're conflating how the data is serialized to/from disk vs how the data structure operates in memory. They're very, very loosely related, so there's almost no insight to be gained into the performance of the in-memory data structure through inspection of the serialized data.

Comment: The big O complexity of creating a pivot table from n lines of data and m rows+columns+filters is basically O(n*m). There are some edge cases where it can blow out to O(n log n * m) but that's when you've set up the pivot table in an irrational manner (added a double value as a row AND sorted it). It SHOULD be fast.

Comment: @MineR would you want to share a basic implementation of that algorithm using the above sample data (or an example of how it could be O(n logn*m) to show a basic algorithm behind creating the Pivot table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pivot-table performance is based on `Pivot Cache`. Although there is very little information on this subject (I mean the lack of official documentation), I've found some interesting posts and MS documentation.

***Definition***:

**`Pivot Cache` is a special memory area where pivot table records are saved**.

[image]

> When you create a `Pivot Table`, Excel takes a copy of the source data and stores it in the `Pivot Cache`. The `Pivot Cache` is held in Excel’s memory. You can’t see it but that’s the data the Pivot Table references when you build your Pivot Table.
>
> **`This enables Excel to be very responsive to changes in the Pivot Table but it can also double the size of your file`**. After all, the Pivot Cache is just a duplicate of your source data so it makes sense that your file size will potentially double.

Please, use this [**link**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.pivottablewizard) and this [**link**](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/aggregations-in-power-pivot-f36a448a-4962-4baf-baa2-68187b6387ce) for further information as a starting reference point.

Also, you can read [Pivot Cache in Excel 101](https://trumpexcel.com/pivot-cache-excel/) and [Excel Pivot Cache 101](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-pivot-cache) posts to find out what it is and what side effects it has.

Here are some VB code snippets and examples how to use [**PivotCache object**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcache).

Here's a code written in C# that allows you to create an Excel workbook with some `Pivot Tables` which, of course, use `Pivot Cache`:

```
System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
 
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {

    class Program {
 
        static void Main(string[] args) {
 
            Excel.Application objApp;
            Excel.Workbook objBook;
            Excel.Sheets objSheets;
            Excel.Workbooks objBooks;
 
            string command = (@"SELECT * FROM dbo.Client");
 
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionStringByName("CubsPlus"))) {

                DataTable data = new DataTable();

                try {
                    connection.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    StackTrace st = new StackTrace(new StackFrame(true));
                    StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(0);
                    Console.WriteLine (e.Message + "\n" + "Method" + sf.GetMethod().ToString() + "\n" + "Line" + sf.GetFileLineNumber().ToString());
                }
                try {
                    data = DataTools.SQLQueries.getDataTableFromQuery(connection, command);
 
                    if (data == null) {
                        throw new ArgumentNullException();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {

                    StackTrace st = new StackTrace(new StackFrame(true));
                    StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(0);
                    Console.WriteLine (e.Message + "\n" + "Method" + sf.GetMethod().ToString() + "\n" + "Line" + sf.GetFileLineNumber().ToString());
                }
 
                objApp = new Excel.Application();

                try {     
                    objBooks = objApp.Workbooks;
                    objBook = objApp.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
                    objSheets = objBook.Worksheets;
 
                    Excel.Worksheet sheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)objSheets[1];
                    sheet1.Name = "ACCOUNTS";
                    string message = DataTools.Excel.copyDataTableToExcelSheet(data, sheet1);

                    if (message != null) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Problem importing the data to Excel");
                        Console.WriteLine(message);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                         
                    //CREATE A PIVOT CACHE BASED ON THE EXPORTED DATA
                    Excel.PivotCache pivotCache = objBook.PivotCaches().Add(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase,sheet1.UsedRange);
 
                    Console.WriteLine(pivotCache.SourceData.ToString());
                    
                    Console.ReadLine();
 
                    //WORKSHEET FOR NEW PIVOT TABLE
                    Excel.Worksheet sheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)objSheets[2];
                    sheet2.Name = "PIVOT1";
                    
                    //PIVOT TABLE BASED ON THE PIVOT CACHE OF EXPORTED DATA
                    Excel.PivotTables pivotTables = (Excel.PivotTables)sheet2.PivotTables(Missing.Value);
                    Excel.PivotTable pivotTable = pivotTables.Add(pivotCache, objApp.ActiveCell, "PivotTable1", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
 
                    pivotTable.SmallGrid = false;
                    pivotTable.TableStyle = "PivotStyleLight1";
 
                    //ADDING PAGE FIELD
                    Excel.PivotField pageField = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields("ParentName");
                    pageField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlPageField;
 
                    //ADDING ROW FIELD
                    Excel.PivotField rowField = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields("State");
                    rowField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
 
                    //ADDING DATA FIELD
                    pivotTable.AddDataField(pivotTable.PivotFields("SetupDate"), "average setup date", Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlAverage);
 
                    ExcelSaveAs(objApp, objBook, @"J:\WBK");
 
                    objApp.Quit();
                }     
                catch (Exception e) {

                    objApp.Quit();
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
 
        static string ExcelSaveAs(Excel.Application objApp, Excel.Workbook objBook, string path) {
            try {
                objApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
                objBook.SaveAs(path, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel7, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                objApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                StackTrace st = new StackTrace(new StackFrame(true));
                StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(0);
                return (e.Message + "\n" + "Method" + sf.GetMethod().ToString() + "\n" + "Line" + sf.GetFileLineNumber().ToString());
            }
        }
        static string GetConnectionStringByName(string name) {
            //ASSUME FAILURE
            string returnValue = null;
 
            //Look for the name in the connectionStrings section
            ConnectionStringSettings settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name];
 
            // If found, return the connection string
            if (settings != null) {
                returnValue = settings.ConnectionString;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a code written in VB that allows us to create a new `Pivot Cache` for selected `Pivot Table`:

```
Sub SelPTNewCache()

    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set pt = ActiveCell.PivotTable
    
    If pt Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Active cell is not in a pivot table"
    Else
        Set wsTemp = Worksheets.Add
        
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
            SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
            SourceData:=pt.SourceData).CreatePivotTable _
            TableDestination:=wsTemp.Range("A3"), _
            TableName:="PivotTableTemp"
        
        pt.CacheIndex = wsTemp.PivotTables(1).CacheIndex
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wsTemp.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
exitHandler:
        Set pt = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

> **1.** In your `asd.js` file there are the following elements:

– `s` stands for a string value

– `n` stands for a numeric value

– `d` stands for a date value

– `x` stands for an index value

– `v` indicates a value itself

**So, let's translate in human language a data contained in `F2` cell of this table**:

[image]

```
<x v="0"/>
```

A value of `0` is an `zero index` in array of Strings where abbreviations of USA states are stored. The first index in this array retrieves `Arizona` for us. I don't know why the cell in next row contains lowercased `az` and all the others contain uppercased `AZ` but I'm sure it's not about `Shared Record`.

> **2.** I haven't found any useful information on the internal C/C++ Struct that Excel uses in-memory for its pivotCache.

And, at last:

> **3.** Here's a [LINK](http://officeopenxml.com/SScontentOverview.php) containing useful info regarding "helper information" in third extra question.

P.S.

**About Big O notation**.

> [Big O notation](https://mytechnetknowhows.wordpress.com/2014/12/20/o-notation-with-c-csharp-my-take/) is used in Computer Science to describe the performance or complexity of an algorithm. Big O specifically describes the worst-case scenario, and can be used to describe the execution time required or the space used (in memory or on disk) by an algorithm. `Big O notation` is a measure of the complexity of your program in terms of the size of the input.

- **`O(1)`** stands for algorithm that always executes in the same time regardless of the size of the input data set.
- **`O(N)`** stands for algorithm whose performance grows linearly and in direct proportion to the size of the input data set.
- **`O(N*N)`** stands for algorithm whose performance is directly proportional to the size's square of the input data set.
- **`T(N) = O(log N)`** stands for algorithm whose performance depends on logarithmic time. Algorithms taking logarithmic time are commonly found in operations on [binary trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) or when using binary search.

But good sorting algorithms are harshly **`O(N log N)`**. An algorithm's example with this efficiency can be **merge sort**, which ***breaks up an array into two halves, sorts those two halves by recursively calling itself on them, and then merging the result back into a single array***.

Here's an abstract C# code's snippet showing how **`O(N log N)`** algorithm works (approximately the same approach can be used for creating a pivot table):

```
public static int[] MergeSort(int[] inputItems, int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
    if (lowerBound < upperBound) {
        int middle = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
        MergeSort(inputItems, lowerBound, middle);
        MergeSort(inputItems, middle + 1, upperBound);
 
        int[] leftArray = new int[middle - lowerBound + 1];
        int[] rightArray = new int[upperBound - middle];
 
        Array.Copy(inputItems, lowerBound, leftArray, 0, middle - lowerBound + 1);
        Array.Copy(inputItems, middle + 1, rightArray, 0, upperBound - middle);
 
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (int count = lowerBound; count < upperBound + 1; count++) {
            if (i == leftArray.Length) {
                inputItems[count] = rightArray[j];
                j++;
            }
            else if (j == rightArray.Length) {
                inputItems[count] = leftArray[i];
                i++;
            }
            else if (leftArray[i] <= rightArray[j]) {
                inputItems[count] = leftArray[i];
                i++;
            }
            else {
                inputItems[count] = rightArray[j];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    return inputItems;
}
```

Comment: cheers for the answer. This is super helpful and has pointed me in the correct direction. Are you able to see what the actual pivot cache is in excel?

Comment: David, could you tell me what you exactly mean saying `...what the actual pivot cache is...` ?

Comment: sure, let me update the questions. Apologies for the slow follow-up.

Comment: wow this is a very comprehensive and great answer. Any possibility you could give a very brief example of the `O(n*m)` complexity algorithm in C# for example, that one of the comments mentions about generating the pivot table cache to complete the answer / I'd award the bounty

Comment: David, that's all I could find.

Comment: Thanks a lot, David! I've been developing macOS apps and I don't have a spare time for any other work. Thank you for proposal.

Answer (score 4):

- Pivot tables are in contrast to popular belief not just an Excel
  feature but present in a lot of applications dealing with tabularly
  structured numerical data – pivot tables are the visual and
  interactive result of a general concept of data aggregation depending
  on categories.
- Pivot Tables are always linked to the data they are derived from.
- When a Pivot table is created Excel builds a special memory cache
  containing your data in the background. This pivot cache stores a
  copy of the data that is in the source data range.
- Pivot tables share a pivot cache if they reference the same source
  data range.  This helps reduce file size and prevents us from having
  to refresh each pivot table that shares the same source data range.

[image]

- The relationships between pivot tables and pivot caches can get
  complicated.  Especially since the pivot cache is stored in the
  background, and there is no way to see which pivot tables are sharing
  a pivot cache in the workbook.

[Anatomy of Spreadsheet File](http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML-xlsx.php)

- [PivotCache Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/cc862621(v=office.14)) PivotCache.When the object is serialized out as
  xml, its qualified name is x:pivotCache.
- [PivotCache Members (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff194008%28v%3Doffice.14%29) Represents the memory cache for a
  PivotTable report.
- Represents a base class that all elements in an [Office Open XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.openxmlelement?view=openxml-2.8.1)
  document derive from.
- The [OpenXML specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) is a large and complicated beast.
- [cacheField (PivotCache Field)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/cc819512(v=office.14)) Represent a single field in the
  PivotCache. This definition contains information about the field,
  such as its source, data type, and location within a level or
  hierarchy. The sharedItems element stores additional information
  about the data in this field. If there are no shared items, then
  values are stored directly in the pivotCacheRecords part.
- Defines the [SharedItems Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.shareditems?view=openxml-2.8.1). When the object is serialized out
  as xml, its qualified name is x:sharedItems.
- [How to create pivot table in C++](https://www.easyxls.com/manual/tutorials/cpp/create-excel-pivot-table.html)
- [How do update pivot table datafrom C# code](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1106962/How-do-I-update-pivot-table-data-from-Csharp-code)
- [Use C++ to show memory use in an Excel Pivot table](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/calvin_hsia/2016/04/01/use-c-to-show-memory-use-in-an-excel-pivot-table/)
- [How to create excel pivot table from C++ (ole/com without mfc)](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1095045/How-to-create-excel-pivot-table-from-Cplusplus-ole)
- [How to Create Pivot Table in Excel in C#.NET Code](https://www.iditect.com/tutorial/excel-pivottable/)
- [How to Export Data to One Worksheet and Create Pivot Table in
  Another Based on the Data](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d2dcfc/how-to-export-data-to-one-worksheet-and-create-pivot-table-i/)
- [How to add PivotTables and Slicers to MS Excel programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/17/excel-pivottables-slicers-programmatically/)